# GDDR5 memory addressing confusion

Tags: memory

I'm trying to develop a GDDR5 controller and am slightly confused regarding the JEDEC spec document - the different memory configuration possibilities all seem to be short three address bits to attain the capacity specified...?

For example 512M memory, 32x mode, with 8 banks (all larger configurations use 16): 
Row address bits are A0-A11 (12)
Column address bits are A0-A5 (6)
Bank address bits are: BA0-BA2 (3)
(See JDEC spec document JSED212B.01 pg 12 Table 7 and Table8)

But that only addresses 2^12*2^6*2^3=2Mi addressed locations each of x32bits = 64Mbs....

You can do the same with any other configuration listed and still not get the capacity specified. This isn't related to bank groups or the fact that GDDR5 multiplexes it's address lines but clearly there's something else non-standard (different to DDR3) that I'm missing?

Anyone with insights please advise?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find this information anywhere so in case someone else needs it linking to where is was answered very nicely!

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2194505/gddr5-memory-addressing.html

In brief GDDR5 burst access is limited to a single column address making an address location equivalent to x32*8 burst length bits in size